# Linked server to Dataverse

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, common-data-service, dataverse

How Create a linked server to Dataverse from SQL Server ?

I would like to know if i can use linked servers to do this and what are the correct properties for the connection. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [Dataverse - Use SQL to query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query) and [Cannot Add "Active Directory - Password" as Linked Server into my SSMS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285640)?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics 365 (Dataverse) is not available through SSMS.